# Error when converting float to datetime

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert a float in the format yyyymmdd to datetime. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the correct style code for that format is 112.

Code:

```
select
    convert(datetime,cast(myDate as numeric),112)
from MyTable
```

Error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

I get the same error without the `cast as numeric` part. I've been looking around for a couple hours, but I haven't been able to find anything that fixes this. If you know a better way to convert the float to a datetime I would be open to that idea.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**
Here is the working code:

```
SELECT
    case when isdate(CAST(CAST(myDate AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8))) = 1
            then CAST(CAST(CAST(myDate AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)
        end
from MyTable
```

I wrapped it in the `isdate` because there were a few invalid dates in there. Thanks to Matt for the help.

**EDIT2**
Better version:

```
SELECT
    TRY_CAST(CAST(CAST(myDate AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Stop storing dates as float

Comment: How do you know that you don't have a value like `20140230` in myDate field?

Comment: The "112" designates the format of the output value, not the input value.

Comment: Further, you will notice that the date format code is used to convert DATETIME to VARCHAR, not FLOAT to DATETIME.

Comment: I wasn't the one who decided to store dates as floats. I just have to deal with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you must convert the FLOAT to a VARCHAR. And since FLOAT has a number of decimal points, it must first be converted to an INT.

```
DECLARE @myDate FLOAT
SET @myDate = 20140721
SELECT CAST(CAST(@myDate AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8))
--20140721
```

Then you can convert the VARCHAR to DATE or DATETIME format.

```
DECLARE @myDate FLOAT
SET @myDate = 20140721
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(@myDate AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)
--2014-07-21
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a few invalid dates, so I had wrapped it in a an `isdate`, but this works great.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I didn't know about TRY_CAST. That is a great thing to have.

Comment: Yeah, that TRY_CAST really cleans up the code nicely in your solution!